# add navigation bar to UITableViewController without using NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add Navigation Bar to a `UITableViewController` **without** using `NavigationController`.

So in `viewDidLoadMethod` of `MyUITableViewController`, I create a `Navigation Bar` using CGRect.

```
UINavigationBar * navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 50)];
```

Then I present  MyUITableViewController from MainViewController

```
   [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
```

At this point my `MyUITableViewController` is overlapping with `NavBar`

I was thinking of creating tableViewController with initWithFram(x, y, width, height) to compensate for NavBar.

But I was not sure what height I should use and how to come up with a value. **Would it have the correct scroll behavior??**

What is the right way? Please note at this point I do not want to use Navigation Controller.

Is it possible w/o Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use UITableViewController, but use simply UIViewController, add a UITableView object on it, and also implement the 2 protocols for table views.

You can resize the table view as you need, you can set its origin Y coordinate to 44 or 64 if you also need the status bar visible.

You can add a UINavigationBar object on top of it.

I hope doing this will help you solve the problem.